# Gtk3: Size of a widget in GtkFixed

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to move my GUI library from gtk2 to gtk3 and have some problems. One of them is that I can't set the size of some widgets like GtkComboBoxText, GtkEntry, GtkSpinButton to a value I want. All widgets are placed in GtkFixed, and I set the size with gtk_widget_set_size_request(). It worked correctly in gtk2. But in gtk3 I can't set the height of a combobox and entry or a width of a spin less than some value. Does the GtkFixed no longer work as before?

Ok, I've found how to change some properties, using the GtkCssProvider, and now I can decrease the widget height, setting the "min-height" CSS option. But I still can't make the width smaller, the "min-width" doesn't help. I set, for example, "entry { min-height: 8px; min-width: 8px; }" - the height becomes the same as I set it with gtk_widget_set_size_request(), but the width doesn't decrease below some value ( ~120px).

Comment: Progress, dude.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in your GTK3 CSS theme. If you have control over that it would be easier than `GtkCssProvider`.

Anyway your problem with entry width is probably due to [left and right image](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.20/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry.description) that also have `min-width`.

Keep in mind that `gtk_widget_set_size_request` is a request for minimal size, not a fixed value. I have found, that using [GtkBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.20/GtkBox.html) gives better results than `GtkFixed`.